# Make a request to specific app engine instance

Tags: google-app-engine

There is a way to do so in in cloud foundry and it was useful for a plethora of things. I was curious if app engine had a similar mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending a request to a specific service instance is only possible in the standard environment and only if manual scaling is used.

From the standard environment [Targeted routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#targeted_routing):

> If you are using [manually-scaled services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#manual_scaling), you can target and
>   send a request to a instance by including the instance ID. The
>   instance ID is an integer in the range from 0 up to the total number
>   of instances that are running, and can be specified as follows:
>
> **Sends a request to a specific service and version within a specific instance:**
>
> ```
> https://[INSTANCE_ID]-dot-[VERSION_ID]-dot-[SERVICE_ID]-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com
> http://[INSTANCE_ID].[VERSION_ID].[SERVICE_ID].[MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN]
> ```
>
> **Note**: Targeting an instance is not supported in services that are configured for auto scaling or basic scaling. The instance ID must be
>   an integer in the range from 0, up to the total number of instances
>   running. Regardless of your scaling type or instance class, it is not
>   possible to send a request to a specific instance without targeting a
>   service or version within that instance.

From the flexible environment [Targeted routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-routed#targeted_routing):

> **Note**: In the flexible environment, targeting an instance is not supported. It is not possible to send requests directly to a specific
>   instance.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks